# Flutter textfield expand as user types

Tags: flutter

I have a textfield and need to have multi-line as below so that the text wraps, however it takes up the space of all the lines that is defined in maxLines.  I want to be able to have it look like 1 line and expand as the text wraps.  Any ideas of how to do this is flutter?

```
new TextField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Reply',
                  labelText: 'Reply:',
                ),
                autofocus: false,
                focusNode: _focusnode,
                maxLines: 1,
                controller: _newreplycontroller,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
              ),
```

Comment: A growable `TextField` is not available in flutter as of now.

Comment: It is @HemanthRaj, it's just not very well documented.  You should probably also be able to make it grow horizontally with some kind of `Flexible` or `Expanded`, although I'm not sure that'd ever be a good idea

Comment: The question seems to more likely about growing vertically. I've digged into the code and there is no option to automatically grow vertically.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Set `maxLines` to null and it will auto grow *vertically*.

It's documented (but not entirely clearly) [here](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/TextField/maxLines.html) (edit: I've created a PR to update this, which I should've done to begin with for this question ;). To figure it out I ended up looking at the code for `TextField` and its superclass(es), seeing what the behavior would be if set to null.

So your code should be as follows:

```
new TextField( 
  decoration: const InputDecoration(
    hintText: 'Reply',
    labelText: 'Reply:',
  ),
  autofocus: false,
  focusNode: _focusnode,
  maxLines: null,
  controller: _newreplycontroller,
  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
),
```

If you're trying to make it autogrow *horizontally*, you probably shouldn't - at least not based on the text content.  But I'm asuming you want to make it autogrow vertically.

Comment: Setting `maxLines` to `null` will grow it horizontally not vertically I think. Hope there must be a work around at lease to grow vertically

Comment: ^ That's the opposite. It will grow vertically, not horizontally.

Comment: Yes.  The horizontal width will be determined by the constraints of the container - that's a bit easier to control, but probably harder to make auto-grow.  But I'm not so sure it'd ever be a good idea to auto-grow horizontally, even in a tablet (?)

Comment: Vertically is what I was looking for and this works just as exepected.  Thanks

Comment: @DanField, But what if i want to bound the user to max 4 line and with those 4 lines text field will increase height as text inputted.

Comment: @AnandSuthar - things have changed a little since this answer.  You can now set minLines and maxLines in some more configurations, but I don't know that this has made it to stable just yet.  You can try on dev (or maybe beta).

Answer (score 25):

Using this should do the trick:

```
keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
minLines: 1,
maxLines: 20,
maxLength: 1000,
```

Adding the minLines and MaxLines is important in order to get the required behaviour, whereas maxLength is a treat!

Maybe too late, but better late than never!

Comment: Thanks for the minLines trick. Otherwise textfield does not return back to it's original size when you start deleting!

Answer (score 10):

As shown in the first answer, setting maxLines to null will do the trick. However this would allow the textfield to grow infinitely.

To have more control, set minLines to 1 and maxLines as needed.
Hope this helps!

Code Sample:
    TextField(minLines:1,maxLines:8)

Answer (score 10):

The accepted answer works great for growing vertically. If you'd like the `TextField` to start small and expand **horizontally** as the user types, you can do the following:

```dart
IntrinsicWidth(
  child: TextField(...
),
```

In my case I wanted it centered on the screen (horizontally), so I did:

```
Center(
   child: IntrinsicWidth(
      child: TextField()
   )
)
```

Answer (score 5):

[image]

If you want to set a predefined height, use `expands: true`:

```
SizedBox(
  height: 200,
  child: TextField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter a message'),
    maxLines: null,
    expands: true,
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Setting to null was working the same as setting to 1 (it grows horizontally just one line).

I think you have to set minLines and maxLines.
I'm using minLines: 1 and maxLines: 2 and when the first line reaches the end it expands another line. When the second line reaches the end it scroll the second to the first and creates the third line. So you will have to set maxLenght too.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use this;

```
TextField get _text => TextField(
  maxLines: null,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    constraints: BoxConstraints(
        maxHeight: responsiveHeight,
        maxWidth: responsiveWidth),
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        horizontal: responsiveHorizontalPadding,
        vertical: responsiveVerticalPadding),
    disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
    border: InputBorder.none,
    enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
    isDense: false,
  ));
```

Answer (score 0):

@Rabi Roshan,

> As shown in the first answer, setting maxLines to null will do the
> trick. However this would allow the textfield to grow infinitely.
>
> To have more control, set minLines to 1 and maxLines as needed. Hope
> this helps!

Thank you so much!

I also prefer this version much more because it will only expand if the user inputs more than one line. And if it exceeds the maxLines, it will scroll vertically which is what should normally happen and what all big Chat Apps use.

Answer (score 0):

> textfield and need to have multi-line as below so that the text wraps, however it takes up the space of all the lines that is defined in maxLines. I want to be able to have it look like 1 line and expand as the text wraps

```
Container(
            child: new TextField (
              keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
              minLines: 1,
              maxLines: 10,
              decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                      const Radius.circular(10.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  filled: true,
                  hintStyle: new TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[800]),
                  hintText: "Type in your text",
                  fillColor: Colors.white70),
            ),
            padding: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 16.0, 16.0, 16.0),
          );
```

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling a lot and found this to be the cleanest outcome:
This starts from 1 line and would expand until 3 lines (set by ConstrainedBox)

```
Expanded(
  child: ConstrainedBox(
    constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 80),
    child: TextField(
      maxLines: null, // Allows unlimited lines
      onChanged: (value) { },
      decoration: const InputDecoration(
        border: InputBorder.none,
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```