# Flutter: BoxConstraints forces an infinite height

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to use the `expand` attribute on `TextFormField` widget.

My code looks like this:

```dart
body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          ListTile(
            leading: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage: CachedNetworkImageProvider(
                currentUser.photoUrl
              )
            ),
            title: Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              width: 250.0,
              child: TextFormField(
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                  color: Colors.white
                ),
                cursorColor: Colors.white,
                maxLines: null,
                minLines: null,
                expands: true,
                controller: captionController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Write something...',
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                  ),
                  fillColor: Colors.blue
                )
              )
            )
          ),
  ]
)
```

The problem I have is that, every time I run the code, I am getting the error: `BoxConstraints forces an infinite height`. Please how do i expand the height of the textfield when the length of its content overflows it.

Answer (score 1):

Try providing a finite height to the `Container()`. `expands` tries to size the `TextFormField` according to the parent height which was `null` in your case.

```
  body: ListView(
    children: <Widget>[
      ListTile(
        leading: CircleAvatar(
          backgroundImage: CachedNetworkImageProvider(
            currentUser.photoUrl
          )
        ),
        title: Container(
          height: 200.0, // Add your own custom height here
          //Rest of the code is same
        )
      ),
    ]
  ),
```

Comment: Hey there. After i added the ```height```, the error left but i notice that the text field doesn't expand. My bad, i didn't test the expand part when i first accepted this as the answer. My goal is to make the text field expand vertically but instead, the text field is turning into a scroll view after the entered text overflows the height.

Comment: I presume that ```height``` is the same as using ```maxLines``` but when i tried using ```expands```, flutter asked me to set ```maxLines``` and ```minLines``` to null.

Comment: I just provided an answer which fixed the error you were having. So I think accepting the answer was the right thing to do here. Anyway, after reading your comment I believe for your use-case `expands` is not the way to go. Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49110989/flutter-textfield-expand-as-user-types). It might have what you're looking for.

Comment: At the end of the question, i added ```while still using expands``` meaning that i still want the ```expands``` behavior to remain. The goal of the question is not to eliminate the error only. Also, i already checked that question, none of the answers there matches what i want to achieve.

Comment: What i expect to happen while using ```expands``` is for the height of the text field to increase when the length of its content is starting to overflow it, but instead, the text field is turning into a scrollable one. I want the height to actually increase so that all the content entered is shown at once without having to scroll

Comment: *Please how do I fix this error while still using expands*. This text does not let users know that you wish to expand the textfield height when it overflows. It only means that you want the error to go away. You can't expect users to automatically infer what you want by asking an ambiguous question. 
You can refer the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section so that this thing won't happen in the future. Cheers!

Comment: Okay, i've tried editing the question. If it still seems ambiguous, please edit it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Explaination ==>

Solution 1) When you use a ListView it has virtually infinte amounts of space to expand upon, that is the reason the errors shows up. Now changing the ListView ==> Column limits the expanding space to the size of the viewport.
And also wrap the ListTile with a Expanded widget which will mean the ListTile widget will consume the entire space available to the Column

DartPad Link ==> https://dartpad.dev/0acdc3ebef330f717813fc5163de0ccb

Solution 2) Now assuming you still require it to be a List View, for as to have multiple elements and have them be scrollable. Now to achieve this what you can do is wrap you Listtile with a Container and give the Container some BoxConstraints with its maxHeight being the size of the viewport which you can get from a MediaQuery

DartPad Link ==> https://dartpad.dev/22f30c0aaab31bff8627226cc21875f1